# implement Expand All and Collapse All button in custom build activity timeline lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, activity-timeline

I am trying to build a custom Activity Timeline using lwc. I want to have a button to expand all activity nodes and collapse all activity nodes on click . This is similar to expand all button in standard Activity Timeline.

The issue which i am facing is when click on ExpandAll button on parent , i am calling the child method . After that only the first node is getting expand

Before clicking

[image]

After clicking "Expand All" button

[image]

How to make all the nodes to expand when button is clicked.

Below is my code.

Parent HTML

```
    <lightning-card class="slds-m-top_medium">
        <template if:true={timelineGroups}>
  <lightning-button variant="base" label="Expand All" title="Expand All" onclick={handleClick}
                class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
            <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open active-section-name={activeSections}>
                <template for:each={timelineGroups} for:item="activityGroup">
                    <lightning-accordion-section name={activityGroup.sectionName} label={activityGroup.name}
                        key={activityGroup.items}>
                        <ul class="slds-timeline">
                            <template for:each={activityGroup.items} for:item="item">
                                <c-activitylineitem key={item} item={item} isexpanded="true"></c-activitylineitem>
                            </template>
                        </ul>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </template>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
```

Parent JS -

```
@track activeSections = [];
    @track timelineGroups;
    connectedCallback() {
        getActivityTimeline({ recordId: this.rowdetails.idtoupdate, includeChildren: false })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                var timelineGroups = result;
                var activeSections = [];
                timelineGroups.forEach(function (timelineGroup, index) {
                    var sectionName = 'Section' + index;
                    activeSections.push(sectionName);
                    timelineGroup.sectionName = sectionName;
                });
                this.activeSections = activeSections;
                this.timelineGroups = timelineGroups;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.isLoaded = false;
                this.error = error;
                this.showToast(this.error, 'Error')
            });

    }

handleClick(e) {
    this.template.querySelector('c-activitylineitem').expandAllNode();
}
```

Child HTML

```
 <template>
    <li>
        <div class={itemStyle}>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">{item.activityTimelineType}</span>
            <div class="slds-media">
                <div class="slds-media__figure">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" title={title} onclick={toggleActivityDetail}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:switch" size="x-small"
                            class="slds-button__icon slds-timeline__details-action-icon">
                        </lightning-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

Child JS

```
  get itemStyle() {
        return this.showDetails ? "slds-timeline__item_expandable slds-is-open" : "slds-timeline__item_expandable";
    }
      @api
        expandAllNode() {
            this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all children and expand them. Note that we have to copy the NodeList in order to iterate over it, so we use a quick array copy. Here's what that looks like:

```
handleClick(e) {
    [...this.template.querySelectorAll('c-activitylineitem')]
      .forEach(node => node.expandAllNode());
}
```

Note that querySelector only returns the first matching item, which is why we need to use querySelectorAll.

Note: I would recommend allowing a way to be explicit about setting the expansion value, otherwise you have a Toggle All instead of an Expand All, as your button suggests:

```
handleClick(e) {
    [...this.template.querySelectorAll('c-activitylineitem')]
      .forEach(node => node.setExpanded(true));
}
```

And for your setExpanded method:

```
  @api
    setExpanded(value) {
        this.showDetails = value;
    }
```

---

That said, you should consider just creating an attribute at the parent level:

```
<template for:each={activityGroup.items} for:item="item">
    <c-activitylineitem key={item} item={item} isexpanded={item.isExpanded}></c-activitylineitem>
</template>
```

And:

```
getActivityTimeline({recordId: this.rowdetails.idtoupdate, includeChildren: false })
.then(result => {
    this.timelineGroups = result.map((v,i) => ({...v, sectionName: `Section${i}`, isExpanded: true}));
    this.activeSections = this.timelineGroups.map((v) => v.sectionName);
})
.catch(error => {
    this.error = error;
    this.showToast(this.error, 'Error');
});
```

Which you can then toggle in the parent:

```
handleClick() {
  this.timelineGroups = [...this.timelineGroups].map(v => ({...v, isExpanded: true }));
}
```

It's generally better to manipulate data at the parent level rather than expose methods on the child directly.

Comment: thank u sfdcfox..